# Implication of the Jacobian map for the structure of the Euclidean space-time

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, operators, quantum-gravity, non-commutative-geometry

I'm listening to Alain Connes "On the Fine-Structure of Space-Time" around [minute 23](https://youtu.be/YGUv5U9vSnI?t=1375) saying that it was disappoing that the solution $Y$ to the equation

$$ \langle Y[D,Y]^{2m} \rangle= \gamma $$

with $D$ a Dirac operator on a (spin Riemannian) manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and $\langle \rangle$ a trace, defines a map

$$\mathcal{M} \xrightarrow{\text{Y}} \mathcal{S}^{2m} $$

to the sphere and the Jacobian of this map $Y$ never vanishes.
The explanation is that, when you pull-back a volume form on the unit sphere, you get the volume form of the Riemannian manifold. This is not clear to me and moreover he adds that *it means that you have a covering* (namely, the map $Y$ is a covering). Is it derived by the [nLab definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cover) of cover?
Now the sphere is simply connected (which is discussed also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2270113/)) but *I don't understand the disappointment* and the physical interpretation as of a sphere of Planck size, even if I see some clarifications in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0977) "Geometry and the Quantum" of Chamseddine

> Theorem 1 gives a concrete realization of this quantization of the
> volume by interpreting the integer $k$ as the number of geometric
> quantas forming the Riemannian geometry $M$. Each geometric quantum is a sphere of arbitrary shape and unit volume (in Planck units).

Can someone shed more light on on this passage ("*at the moment we're only able to find Euclidean space-time which looks like big collections of bubbles*")?

Comment: The formulation of your question might need some editing. Your quote refering to theorem 1 from arxiv.org/abs/1411.0977 could require more contextualisation: it's meaning is clearer with the corrolary 15 (p24).

Comment: To understand the connection between the (Heisenberg like) equation <Y[D,Y]^4 >=gamma with quantization of volume of the manifold "parametrized" by Y, it's worth reading the paragrah XI "Spectral Manifold" in the review article arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003006!

Comment: As reported in their PRL paper arxiv.org/abs/1409.2471  Chamseddine, Connes and Mukhanov aimed at using the operator theoretic equation you mentioned as some equation of motion of a field theory Y on M (in a spectral geometric framework). Their (preliminary) disappointment comes from the fact that this specific equation implies the manifold is necessary disconnected which is not a promissing model of Euclidean spacetime to start with...

Comment: … hopefully for them they explain how to refine the equation incorporating a refinement of noncommutative geometry devised by Connes he named "the real structure" (www.alainconnes.org/docs/reality.pdf) which makes it possible to work with any 4D spin Riemannian manifold (a much more encouraging result for a quantum gravity research programme)! The refinement is inspired by the deep Tomita-Takesaki theory presented by Witten in his pedagogical "Notes on Some Entanglement Properties of Quantum Field Theory" arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993.

Comment: @laboussoleestmonpays Thank you so much, that's really more an answer - that I'd be willing to accept - than just some comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heisenberg-like commutation relation $$ \langle Y[D,Y]^{2m} \rangle= \gamma $$  (with $\gamma $ the chirality operator) appeared first in a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2471) then a PRL [article](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.091302).

It was devised by A. Chamseddine, A. Connes and S. Mukhanov, aiming at using it as a tentative equation of motion of some field theory on a manifold in the spectral Non Commutative Geometric framework.

To have some context one needs to know NCG can be seen as a sound mathematical apparatus built to generalise Riemannian geometry and go beyond the classical notion of a manifold. Its operator theoretic language has been largely inspired by quantum mechanics (statistical and relativistic quantum gauge field theories). In general the data of a manifold, its spin and metric structures are encoded by spectral NCG in terms that avoid local charts, using instead relations between an algebra of "position" ($Y$) and Dirac ($D$) operators in a Hilbert space setting. In their original paper Chamseddine, Connes and Mukhanov explain how to use the Feynman slash of real scalar fields to built the proper $Y$ operators and show how their work is a starting point for a quantization of geometry with quanta corresponding to irreducible representations of their Heisenberg-like commutation relation.

Now to understand mathematically the connection between the Heisenberg-like equation and the quantization of the volume of the manifold "parametrized" by $Y$ and $D$ (roughly speaking), it's worth reading the paragraph XI "Spectral Manifold" in this short [review article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003006). To build some physical intuition one may also watch this informative [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4N3TTt9h8A) by Ali Chamseddine.

To answer the question about the "disappointment" Connes talks about in the [video](https://youtu.be/YGUv5U9vSnI?t=1375) it suffices to know that it came from the fact that the Heisenberg-like commutation relation implies the only manifolds where the proper $Y$ and $D$ can "live" are necessary unions of disconnected spheres which is not a promising model for a Euclidean spacetime.

… Hopefully for them they explain in the same article how to refine their equation incorporating a refinement of NCG devised by Connes in this [article](https://alainconnes.org/wp-content/uploads/reality.pdf) named "the real structure". They built then a new commutation relation (refered as a"two-sided" equation) which makes it possible to get any 4D spin Riemannian manifold with quantized volume but connected: a more encouraging result for their quantum gravity research programme one can guess.

Remark: the "real structure" proposed by Alain Connes is inspired by the deep Tomita-Takesaki theory and plays a fundamental role in his vision of NCG. The Tomitat-Takesaki theory is presented by Edward Witten in his pedagogical [Notes on Some Entanglement Properties of Quantum Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993)